# How to check the image from the camera is stored in the device is in a proper format to set it in a image view?

Tags: android, image, camera

In my application I use a camera to take a picture and store it in a specified folder,then I get the image from the folder and set it to an image view.

What is I am facing is the image in the folder is being converting it into to proper jpeg format,which takes a few sec to form the image to good format(this problem occurs when I set the image in image view immediately after closing the camera).is there any way(or condition) to check whether the image is in proper format.
or
Is there any way that on click of the camera tick button I can use handler for few seconds to set image to an image view.!!!

Comment: You can try an `AsyncTask`to store the Image. Then override the `onPostExecute` Method to display the Image

Comment: Do you use MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent?

Comment: yes...this intent=new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

Comment: @Wicked161089...async task is not working in my case..

Answer (score 0):

What I've done was to show the image view photo from camera and store it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch(requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
                    if (data != null) {
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                        // Guardamos la imagen
                        // Create the File where the photo should go
                        File photoFile = null;
                        try {
                            photoFile = createImageFile();
                            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                            if (photoFile != null && isExternalStorageReadable() && isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(photoFile);
                                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                                fOut.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            // Error occurred while creating the File
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error creando el fichero para guardado de imagen del alumno");
                        }

                        imagenAlumno.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Devulción de foto null");
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

The methods used are these:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String imageFileName = "fileName";

    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + File.separator + "Folder");

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    return image;
}

public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice that you use the Bitmap returned from camera to show the image and then you can store the image as you want. Let me know if that helps you cos I'm not sure if this solve what you are asking for.